# iptables port forwarding from public ip but not from 127.0.0.1

Tags: iptables, nat, port

i have an issue with my network setting and i need a port forwarding a bit advanced.

I need :
- All packets that arrive on my public_ip on port 54321 to be forward on port 12345 but i don't want any translation when it come from localhost.

Thanks

Comment: add a "! -i lo"  ? From the man : [!] -i, --in-interface name
              Name of an interface via which a packet was received (only for packets entering the INPUT, FORWARD and PREROUTING chains).  When the "!" argument  is  used  before  the
              interface  name, the sense is inverted.  If the interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match.  If this option is omitted, any
              interface name will match.

Comment: Post what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using REDIRECT of `iptables`.

```
    iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d <public ip> -p tcp --dport 54321 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345
```

If you need `udp`, just change the protocol.